# The R %in% operator

Tags: r

In `R`, I have am running the following script:

```
> 1:6 %in% 0:36
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Which is clearly producing a logical vector.  I have read the documentation but can't seem to find an operator that would return a scalar based on the result, such that `1:6 %in% 0:36` would simply return `TRUE` while having `0:37 %in% 0:36` return `FALSE`.

Does one exist?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can use `all`

```
> all(1:6 %in% 0:36)
[1] TRUE
> all(1:60 %in% 0:36)
[1] FALSE
```

On a similar note, if you want to check whether any of the elements is TRUE you can use `any`

```
> any(1:6 %in% 0:36)
[1] TRUE
> any(1:60 %in% 0:36)
[1] TRUE
> any(50:60 %in% 0:36)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Additionally, you can can define your own operator by wrapping match in all: `%allin%` <- function(x,table) {all(match(x,table,nomatch = 0L) > 0L)}