# Create a subset of a data.frame by removing specific rows

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, subset

I am trying to subdivide a "mother data.frame" into three data.frames: the mother data.frame, called `dfrm`, has different variables including `id` (identification), `time` (three time points), a numerical variable `Ht`, and a factor `fac` with 3 levels depending on Ht.

I created 2 data.frames, `dfrm2` and `dfrm3`, using the `ddply` function, sorting subjects having a certain level of the `fac` variable AT EACH OF THE THREE TIME POINTS:

```
id  <-  rep(c(seq(1,50,1)),3)
    time  <- factor(rep(c("day1", "day2", "day3"), c(50,50,50)), levels=c("day1", "day2", "day3"), labels=c("day1", "day2", "day3"), ordered=TRUE)
    Ht  <- rnorm(150, mean=30, sd=3)
    A  <- rnorm(150, mean=7, sd=10)
    df  <-  as.data.frame(cbind(id,time,Ht,A))
    head(df)
    fac <- factor(cut(df$Ht, breaks=c(1,30,35,100), labels=c("<30%","<35%", ">35%"), include.lowest=TRUE))
    dfrm  <- as.data.frame(cbind(df,fac))

library(plyr)
dfrm2  <-  ddply(dfrm, "id", function(x) if(all(x$fac=="<30%")) x else NULL)
nrow(dfrm2)
    [1] 18
dfrm3  <-  ddply(dfrm, "id", function(x) if(all(x$fac=="<35%")) x else NULL)
nrow(dfrm3)
    [1] 6
```

I would like to create the third data.frame, with all the rows that have not been selected in `dfrm2` or `dfrm3`. Up until now I was not successful.

I think the idea could be to indicate R to remove rows from the mother `dfrm` according to `id` not selected yet. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `split function`:

```
l<-split(df,dfrm$fac)
names(l)<-paste0("data",1:length(levels(dfrm$fac)))
```

Updated as per comments:

```
 dfrm4<-dfrm[!(dfrm$id %in% dfrm2$id|dfrm$id %in% dfrm3$id),]
    > dim(dfrm4)
    [1] 117   5
```

Comment: Thank you Metrics, but dfrm2 and dfrm3 have been created with rows from "id" having the same level of "fac" at three time points (i do not want to split the mother dfrm like you suggest)

Comment: Your id var is from 1:50. This will generates 50 dataframes if your condition is satisfied. Are you really looking for this?

Comment: No. The code i indicated works well for the two first data.frames (dfrm2 and 3) : ddply selects all three rows form "id" that have a certain level of "fac" on each of the 3 occasions. Didi you try it? it works. My problem is to create the last data.frame.

Comment: That will give you a empty dataframe. I hope you understand what you are doing.

Comment: As indicated in my code, i obtained two data.frames with 18 rows for dfrm2 and 6 rows for dfrm3. I looked at them, they indeed contain observations with the appropriate level of "fac" on each occasions.

Comment: @ den : See my updated answer why you were not able to create third dataframe (dfrm4)?

Comment: thank you. But i am not sur you understand the output i desire: actually it is simple: i want dfrm4 to have all the rows that are not included into dfrm2 or dfrm3.

Comment: No problem. I think there is a way to tell R : "look at id into dfrm2 and dfrm3, and create dfrm 4 by removing these ids from the mother dfrm".

Comment: Please see my updated answer and let me know if that is one what you are looking for

Comment: @ Metrics  : I looks that your answer works fine !! i am confused with  that "%" sign... what does it mean? Thank you anyway!!

Comment: No problem. Whenever you are making comparisons to many values, you can use the `%in%` operator.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385863/the-r-in-operator) for details on `%in%`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `plyr` is the solution to almost every problem in R, but in my opinion this is an exception; bracket subsetting would be clearer & easier.

```
dfrm2 <- dfrm[dfrm$fac=="<30%", ]
dfrm3 <- dfrm[dfrm$fac=="<35%", ]
dfrm4 <- dfrm[dfrm$fac!="<30%" % dfrm$fac!="<35%", ]
```

Comment: @ Drew: thank you but : If you do so, you will create dfrm2 and dfrm3 by selecting ANY row with the indicated level of "fac". I used plyR to select row from "id" having the desired level of fac at EACH of the 3 time points.