# Explanation for R code used to delete column

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, data-science, semantics

Can anyone tell me the piece-by-piece meaning of the following code used to conditionally delete a column of a data frame?

```
df2=df[,!names(df)%in%c("column")]
```

Conditions:
**column** is the column I want to delete from the dataframe **df**. df2 is the new dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
df2=df[,!names(df)%in%c("column")]
```

df is our dataframe. 
So we are choosing columns in df that are not "column".

**Choosing Columns** is done like:

```
df[,mycol]
```

The `names(df)` chooses the column names. 
`!` is a falsifier(negation mark) and tells us that out of the column names in df choose columns that are not "column".

```
!names(df)%in%c("column")
```

We then assign our selection to `df2`(a new dataframe).

**Illustration:**
This chooses all columns that are not `Species.`

```
iris[,!names(iris)%in%c("Species")]


 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
```

What were the original columns?

```
names(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

**The %in% operator** is exhaustively tackled here:
[The R %in% operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385863/the-r-in-operator)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Can you please explain what % is in R? I still don't know what is it.

Comment: This is taken together as `%in%` which is almost(but not exactly) equal to "==". It checks that A is in B`(A%in%B)`. I've added a link to a question that handles the same.